# How to link with specific library ( g++; libstdc++.so.5 and libstdc++.so.6 )

Tags: linker, g++, libstdc++

A simple question - is there any way to make the `g++` linker to link with a specific `libstdc++` library version? I didn't find anything useful in the man page of `gcc`/`g++`, neither in other questions here.

Here's the situation - my application uses a specific shared library, that's built with `libstdc++.so.5` and I want to install and use it on `RHEL5`. So, when I try to build the application on a `RHEL5` machine, I got the warning:

```
warning: libstdc++.so.5, needed by ..the_shared_library_.. may conflict with libstdc++.so.6
```

Installing a `compat-libstdc++` rpm didn't help, the program crashes on a destructor of `std::string`, because of the *incapability*. So, on this `RHEL5` machine I have this:

```
[root@xxx]# ll /usr/lib/libstd*  
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 259532 Aug 21 2006 /usr/lib/libstdc++-3-libc6.2-2-2.10.0.so  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jul 28 19:35 /usr/lib/libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3 -> libstdc++-3-libc6.2-2-2.10.0.so  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Aug 24 15:08 /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5 -> libstdc++.so.5.0.7  
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 733456 Aug 21 2006 /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5.0.7
```

and when I make

```
[root@xxxx]# ldd my_exe  
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00333000)  
...  
libstdc++.so.5 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5 (0x00ddf000)
```

which is bad, as I know it's undefined behavior :/

So, is there any way to build my executable using only `libstdc++.so.5` ? (removing `libstdc++.so.6` is not an option because of many reasons. Static linking is not an option, too ).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the [ABI versions table](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html); the default value for the `-fabi-version` switch changed from 1 to 2 at the same time g++ introduced libstdc++.so.6 with 3.4. This means that to link against the older libstdc++ library you would need to

- find and use the equivalent C++ headers instead of the ones included with your compiler
- recompile all your code (and any other C++ libraries you're using) with `-fabi-version=1`

otherwise you run the risk of ABI incompatibilities. I can't tell you precisely what the changes were but in general it's best to try and keep all C++ code you have compiled with the same compiler version.

Assuming you don't want to try and hack things togther like this I think you have two choices:

1. ask your shared library vendor to recompile the library with your version of GCC for you. This may not be trivial as g++ 3.4 introduced a new stricter C++ parser.
2. ask your vendor which version of g++ they used to compile the library in the first place and use that version to compile your own code. RH might provide a compat-gcc compiler as well as the libstdc++ - I can't remember. However you'll also need down-level versions of all other libraries and OS-provided C++ libraries that you're using, so might be easiest to compile on a VM with an older Red Hat version that had the right compiler.

Comment: Okay, I tried the first option, still nothing .. I'm still waiting for help there, so I don't really think that they will recompile the library.  
About the second one - I need to use the application on a RHEL5 machine, so I don't need older OS libraries, just the libstdc++. If they tell me which gcc version they have used for compiling the oracle library (OCCI 10.2.0.3), I'll make a virtual machine with RHEL5 and the specific gcc version. Hope that will help :/  

Thanks for the response!  

BR,  
Kiril

Comment: Sorry that doesn't help :-/ At a pinch you could run a separate process for the libstdc++.so.5 code and pass data between the two using IPC. It might even be possible to write a C wrapper library with the older GCC and link that into your newer code so there's no C++ boundary between the two but you'd have to be very careful about the library link order there.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's a really good idea! Unfortunately, I don't have time to implement it for this issue, but this would be really helpful for other applications. Very interesting idea. Thanks!

Comment: Hi again!  

I just wanted to tell you that the problem is fixed and, yes, Rup, you're right. The thing, that solved the issue is just a new build of the library, with gcc 3.4.3, instead of 3.2.3 (:  

Thanks for you help!  

Best regards,  
Kiril Kirov