# Creating compiler independent shared objects (C++ with C interface)

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

On Windows DLLs with C interfaces can be used to call C++ code compiled with one compiler (e.g., GCC) from an executable compiled with another one (e.g., MSVC). However, trying to do the same on Linux using SOs has proven to be less easy.

For example, I have the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

extern "C" void __attribute__ ((visibility ("default"))) foo()
{
    [&] () noexcept { std::vector<std::string> bar; bar.emplace_back("foo"); }();
}
```

And create a shared object as follows:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -shared -fvisibility=hidden -fPIC -o libso_test.so so_test.cpp
```

Where `g++` is G++ 5.2.0.

And another file for the main executable:

```
extern "C" void foo();

int main(int, char**)
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

When trying to compile it with the following command:

```
g++-4.8 -L. -o so_test_main so_test_main.cpp -lso_test
```

Where `g++-4.8` is G++ 4.8.1 I get a number of errors (using `g++` instead of `g++-4.8` works fine but defeats the purpose):

```
./libso_test.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
./libso_test.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
./libso_test.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

According to the output of `nm -g -D --defined-only libso_test.so`, aside from the expected symbols `_init`, `_fini`, and `foo` (marked `T`) a large number of other symbols are exported marked `W`.

Although adding `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++` (which I'd like to avoid) to the build command for `libso_test.so` resolves the issue in this particular case, the library I am building has other dependencies which either don't have a static version, or the static version was built without `-fPIC` and is therefore not useable in a shared object.

Result of `ldd libso_test.so`:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff2d570000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /home/<uname>/gcc-5.2.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f8e42404000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8e420ed000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /home/<uname>/gcc-5.2.0/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8e41ed6000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8e41b0e000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8e42986000)
```

How can I hide these symbols properly?

Comment: IIRC, gcc 5.x has a different C++ ABI to gcc 4.x.  So you're explicitly trying something that's not expected to work.  I bet it doesn't work if you skip the shared-library step and just try to link object files from the different compilers.  (It's possible it might work if you create a shared library and link that to the G++ 5 runtime library, and link the main to the G++ 4 runtime, but I'd be wary of such an approach).

Comment: MSVC and GCC on windows have completely different ABIs as well. The whole point of wrapping all C++ classes/calls in a C interface is to be C++ ABI independent.

Comment: Er, yes, but when you come to link those implementations against the C++ library, one of them is then being linked against a different library than it was compiled for.  The only way to avoid that is to link your library with the g++ 5 runtime library explicitly, forbidding `ld.so` from resolving it in the normal way.  That's brittle, which is why I'm wary of it.

Comment: And how would I do that (aside from linking statically which will work for libstdc++ but not for all dependencies)? And why would it be brittle? On windows the dlls a dll loads do not depend on the exe to which they are linked (via import library)

Comment: Adding `-Wl,-Bgroup` does not appear to have any effect. According to `ldd` the library already references the correct libstdc++ (output added to question)

Comment: I think I've reached the end of what I can offer.  All I can suggest now is to [look up 'versioned symbols' with g++](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=g%2B%2B+versioned-symbols) - see [section 3.8 of Ulrich Drepper's _How To Write Shared Libraries_](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf#page=39).  And pass `-Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--no-allow-shlib-undefined`.  I always use `-Wl,--as-needed`, too, to avoid needlessly linking unused libraries.

Comment: Versioned symbols would require an external list of symbols. I'd like to avoid that if possible. In my production code I am already passing `-Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--no-allow-shlib-undefined`.

Comment: Possibly related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/3608010

Comment: Another possible resource - [GCC docs - Multiple ABI Testing](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html#abi.testing.multi)